# Java 8 and Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, java-8

Does anyone knows where i can find a reliable source (docs, JIRA issues, stackoverflow threads, etc) about using Hibernate and Java 8?

I have a bunch of applications using Hibernate, written in Java 7, and i'm interested in migrate its code to Java 8.

For example, is there any known issues on mapping entities with @Temporal attributes on Java 8 (using legacy java.util.Date or JSR-310's new classes)?

Thanks.

Comment: I think [this](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HV-825) is your reliable source.

Comment: Hi @SérgioMichels. I've already seen this JIRA ticket before. I think that Hibernate team have a lot of work to do to turn Hibernate fully compatible with Java 8. However, my concern is how Hibernate will behave when using Java 8 today, without such improvements being made. I've found this [link](http://planet.jboss.org/post/wildfly_8_jdk_8_netbeans_8_java_ee_7_excellent_combo_for_enterprise_java) that shows some code. I haven't tested it yet, but i'll give it a try soon.

Comment: @SérgioMichels take a look at this [link](https://bitbucket.org/montanajava/jpaattributeconverters)